# How to convert a string to a data type mentioned in string in c++

Tags: c++, c, string, type-conversion

I have a string. I want to convert that to datatype mentioned in string.
**eg:** string => "int".
now I have to initialize a variable with content in string.

```
int value;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Since types are fixed at compile time, this will only be possible for some limited, pre-decided list of types, and it will depend on how you want to use the result. Have you made any attempt so far?

Comment: I tried using typedef but it was of no use

Comment: Yes, since `C++` is [*statically typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking), you can't choose the type of a variable at run-time. You can have a bunch of `if` statements that call custom versions of a function though: `if(s=="int") intFoo() else if (s=="float") floatFoo() // ...` (or maybe `foo<int>()`, `foo<float>()`, etc).

Comment: Hint : Use templates. Pass your string to a function and use a switch to create the type you want.

Comment: Actually i want construct the whole function prototype from sting.So this will be a huge task. Is there any other way out?

Comment: @Acme: Can you please give me an example? i am new to cpp

Comment: `Is there any other way out?` - It ain't that easy even in C#

Comment: Read about Templates - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm - this should be your first step. Just look at the stack example.

Comment: @Acme I think you may mislead the asker into thinking you can choose a template parameter at run-time.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: What you describe looks like one solution.  Please describe your problem in general terms; there is probably a better simpler solution.

Comment: I ahve a sting. Let it be like this. "return:float,type1:int,param1:10" Now i have to call a function with these values.ie int arg1=10;float val=fun(arg1);

Comment: @Acme: Thanks Acme. I thought about using template like this. But i didnt get how can i invoke a function using this method

Comment: You invoke a function of a template just like you invoke a function of any class. I do not understand the issue here.

Comment: I am going to invoke an external function, whose return type and args are there in string. How can i use template if function to be called is external. The issue may be my unawareness of templates.Can you please help me

Comment: See my edit and let me kno. If possible explain in detail stepwise.

Comment: @Acme: I think you didnt get what i meant. External function means, an api in a shared library.i am dynamically loading that so using dlopen. now i have to create a function pointer to call that api using dlsym. for that i want to know function prototype which i will get from string. Now how can i call that funtion without knowing the parameters at compile time?

Comment: Well i have no clue about the shared library you are working with so will not be able to help you with that much. But i think if you do some research on `Function Templates` - you will find your solution. I recommend you read that. There is a big gap between and you since i do not have all info and knowledge of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if this will solve your entire problem but just a start:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class myType
{
    public:
     T obj;
     void show()
     {
        cout << obj << endl;
     }
};

void CreateType(char stype)
{
    switch(stype)
    {
        case 'i':
            myType<int> o ;
            o.obj = 10;
            cout << "Created int "  << endl;
            o.show();
            break;
        case 'd':
            myType<double> o1 ;
            o1.obj = 10.10;
            cout << "Created double "  << endl;
            o1.show();
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{ 
    CreateType('i');
    CreateType('d');
     return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string contains something like this: "(type)(separator)(value)",

eg (if separator is "$$$"): "int$$$132" or "double$$$54.123" you should write a little parser.

```
const std::string separator = "$$$";
const unsigned int separatorLength = 3;

std::string str = "int$$$117";
std::string type, value;

unsigned int separatorPosition = str.find(separator);
type = str.substr(0, separatorPosition);
value = str.substr(separatorPosition + separatorLength);

void *variable;
if (type == "int"){
    //convert value to int and store it in void *
} else
if (type == "double"){
    //convert value to double and store it in void *
} else
if (type == "char"){
    //convert value to char and store it in void *
}
```